# Meaning "have a higher opinion of Person A than Person B"

Tags: meaning

Does:

> I have a higher opinion of Person A than Person B.

mean I prefer Person A over Person B or my opinion of Person A is higher than Person B's opinion of Person A? (i.e. I have a higher opinion of Person A than Person B does.)

Comment: Aside from the difference introduced by using “prefer” instead of “having an opinion of”  The sentence could mean either one and context would help disambiguate. Although I will say I naturally jumped to your first option here.

Comment: If you want to disabiguate and say that both opinons are held by you it is acceptable to say "I have a higher opinion of Person A than _of_ Person B", If you want to disambiguate in the opposite direction you could say "I have a higher opinion of Person A than Person B _does_." The nice thing is that both options only add one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means "my opinion of Person A is higher than Person B's opinion of Person A". If you want to express the first idea you have to repeat the preposition "of". You can convince yourself of that by an examination of the following [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+%2A+than+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cof%20%2A%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bof%20him%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20them%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20it%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20curiosity%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20men%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20pity%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20this%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20women%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20fact%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20himself%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cof%20*%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bof%20him%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20them%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20it%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20curiosity%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20men%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20pity%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20this%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20women%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20fact%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20himself%20than%20of%3B%2Cc0) and the pages that correspond to the entries.